I installed Ubuntu on my Samsung s8 and it works fine, but I couldn't install Joomla. There are problems with localhost php and mysql
Can Joomla be installed on Ubuntu running on a android phone?

Why do you need Joomla on a phone? Joomla is a website creation/management system. Do you plan to run a web server on a phone?

You've provided no Ubuntu product & release details for us to provide specific help with.

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release: 24.04
Codename: noble
